# "Insufficient Developer Role" Error with Instagram API during OAuth Flow

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am developing an application using the Instagram API to find the list of people I follow on Instagram who don't follow me back. However, I've run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

When initiating the OAuth 2.0 flow to gain user authorization by redirecting to the Instagram login page, I encounter an error message: "Insufficient Developer Role."

Here's the relevant information about my setup:

1. I have registered my application on the Facebook Developers platform.
2. I have successfully added Instagram as a product to my application.
3. My Instagram account, which I am using for testing, is linked to my Facebook account.
4. My Facebook account is listed as an 'Admin' in the roles section of my Facebook app.

Despite these configurations, the error still persists. I've tried several troubleshooting methods including double-checking roles and permissions, as well as confirming the correct Instagram account is being used. But, none of these seem to rectify the issue.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Andy

I registered an application on the Facebook Developers platform and added Instagram as a product to my application. I set up an OAuth 2.0 flow for user authorization, where the user would be redirected to the Instagram login page to grant my application the necessary permissions.

I expected that after logging into Instagram, the user would be redirected back to my application with an authorization code. This authorization code would then be exchanged for an access token which my application could use to make authorized requests on behalf of the user.

However, when I attempted to initiate this flow by visiting the Instagram login page, I encountered an error message: "Insufficient Developer Role." I had ensured that my Facebook account, which is linked to my Instagram account, is listed as an 'Admin' in the roles section of my Facebook app. Despite this, the error persists.

I expected that as an 'Admin', my role would have the necessary permissions to initiate the OAuth 2.0 flow and obtain an authorization code. However, this was not the result, hence my outreach for help.

Also tried to create a test user but I get this error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnKKV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Your screenshot shows that you were trying to create a Facebook Test User. You need to select "Roles" from the Meta/FB developer app dashboard menu, then select the "Add People" button in the _App Roles_ panel. 

Create a new test user with the "Instagram Test User" role (enter the test user's Insta ID in the search field at the bottom of the _Add People_ modal window). Login to the Insta Test User's account, navigate to "Edit Profile > Apps and Websites" settings & accept the Tester Invite. This should enable authentication as the Test User in your app.